# Preventing widgets from moving when a large content is placed in the same row

Tags: python, canvas, layout, tkinter, widget

I am writing a program in Python that processes some data, then outputs a *plot* of the result in the same *tkinter* window using `Canvas`.

My problem is that I need to place the canvas in the same row as some `Label`; the canvas is big, so it will make the row expand where the label will be pushed down and the interface will not look good.

Here is a screenshot of the interface of the program:

[image]

The label and the canvas are both placed in the same row. When `check` button is clicked, the canvas will show, the row will be expanded, and the label will be pushed down as in the following screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from Tkinter import *

class mclass:
    def __init__(self,  window):
        self.window = window
        self.box = Entry(window)
        self.button = Button (window, text="check", command=self.plot)
        self.plotlabel= Label (window, text="The following is the plot")
        self.box.grid (row=1, column=1)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column= 1)
        self.plotlabel.grid (row=3, column=1)
    def plot (self):
        x=np.array ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
        v= np.array ([16,16.31925,17.6394,16.003,17.2861,17.3131,19.1259,18.9694,22.0003,22.81226])
        p= np.array ([16.23697,     17.31653,     17.22094,     17.68631,     17.73641 ,    18.6368,
            19.32125,     19.31756 ,    21.20247  ,   22.41444   ,  22.11718  ,   22.12453])

        fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))
        a = fig.add_subplot(111)
        a.scatter(v,x,color='red')
        a.plot(p, range(2 +max(x)),color='blue')
        a.invert_yaxis()

        a.set_title ("Estimation Grid", fontsize=16)
        a.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=14)
        a.set_xlabel("X", fontsize=14)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.window)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=3, column= 2)
        canvas.draw()

window= Tk()
start= mclass (window)
window.mainloop()
```

How can I show the canvas without pushing the label down? I've searched around, but couldn't find a similar question. Also, I've tried rowspan in grid method, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: What about putting the canvas in the row after the row where the label is? I am not sure how you want to structure your GUI, but in my opinion I would split the window using 2 frames, one for the widgets on the left side and one for the canvas and the label..

Comment: Thanks nbro, the code I've posted is an example, in the complete program there are many widgets in the same row and after it. I've tried making a frame for the right side only, so in the example I posted the grid of the fame will start row 3 and column 3, then I have set the grid where I specified that the grid should be attached to the frame at column 1 row 1, but this is didn't change anything. Do I need to put frames for both right and left? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I meant 2 frames next to each other, one on the left that occupies all the vertical space, and one on the right for the canvas. In general, frames are very helpful mostly as containers... Many people state that the best way to create layouts is first to use paper and pencil, write it down, and then think how you would do it with your preferable GUI toolkit, in this case tkinter. Another thing you don't need at the beginning is the label with the text `The following is the plot`, since the plot is not shown... You can hide it using `grid_forget`, or simply pack it when it is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot nbro, I've tried it and it worked, and I will apply the grid_forget idea in the code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution involves using both pack and grid. Use pack to place a frame on the left of the main window. This frame will have all of your buttons and input widgets. Use pack to place another frame on the right of the main window. This will contain your plot.

Next, you can use pack or grid to put your buttons or widgets in the left frame. Nothing you do in the right frame will affect the placement of these widgets.

Finally, use pack or grid to put your canvas in the right frame. Nothing you do here will affect your buttons and other widgets.